# How can I get the E2AP packet details and printed it using PcapPlusPlus?

Tags: pcap, libpcap, packet-sniffers, packet-capture, pcapplusplus

I am trying to implement PcapPlusPlus and print E2AP packet details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Unfortunately PcapPlusPlus doesn't support E2AP, but you're more than welcome to add support for it and open a pull request.